# Show that inversion map is a bijection $G/H \to H\! \setminus \! G$, so that number of left cosets always equals the number of right cosets

Tags: group-theory

Show that the inversion map is a bijection $G/H \to H\! \setminus \!
  G$, so that the number of left cosets always equals the number of
  right cosets (even if $G$ is infinite).  Here $G/H$ is the set of
  left cosets and $H \!\setminus\! G$ is the set of right cosets.  (Hint:
  $(aH)^{-1} = H a^{-1}$ so this maps left cosets to right cosets and
  vice-versa, and note that inversion twice is the identity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that $aH=bH\iff Ha^{-1}=Hb^{-1}$ to prove bijectivity.

Comment: I think it's cleaner to use the hint in the OP. You can just directly write down the inverse map. No need to verify injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: That's true. Although, I would think one would need to show that the map is well-defined.  That is $\implies$ of my hint.

Comment: There is no issue with showing the map is well-defined. You just invert the entire coset.